# How to count distinct value using 2 different columns in every 5 mins of a given datetime column?

Tags: python, time-series, aggregate, resampling

I have data in the below format (cols: Time, Subnode, node). I have sorted the node column first and then time, i want to count the number of unique subnode in each node in every 5 mins. The col "No of Subnode" is the output I want. Need to do this for a large dataset. I tried using resampling with no conclusion.

```
Time            Subnode node  No of Subnode
11/23/2020 0:10   a      A       5
11/23/2020 0:11   b      A       5
11/23/2020 0:12   c      A       5
11/23/2020 0:15   d      A       5
11/23/2020 0:10   i      B       2
11/23/2020 0:10   j      B       2
11/23/2020 0:16   k      B       1
11/23/2020 0:16   l      C       4
11/23/2020 0:16   m      C       4
11/23/2020 0:17   n      C       4
11/23/2020 0:18   o      C       4
```

Please help me!

I tried something like this

```
    for i in node:
    temp_df=data[(data['NODE'])==i]
    min_time=min(temp_df['TIME'])
    max_time=max(temp_df['TIME'])
    while min_time<=max_time:
        count=temp_df['TIME'].between(min_time + 
         pd.offsets.DateOffset(minutes=5), temp_df['NODE']).sum()
        temp_df['count'] = np.where(temp_df['NODE']==min_time,count,0 )
        min_time=min_time + pd.offsets.DateOffset(minutes=5)
    return temp_df
```

But it keeps on running. Please let me know a solution

Comment: where is your code?

Comment: Code not inserted because I have not done anything...just many trials.

Comment: What if you have time where you multiple "splits"  like = `[0:11,0:12,0:13,0:20,0:21]`. Here we have 3 subnodes in the first 5 min, but 2 in the last - what would the `No of Subnode` then be ?

Comment: 3 because it is between 0:11-0:15